# Comma separated values in SQL Server returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am writing a statement to create a comma-separated list of column values based on its unique ID value. Some IDs have multiple email values.

I have a `ID, Email, Summary` columns.

For instance:

```
ID | Summary | Email
---+---------+----------------
1  | Hi      | abc@gmail.com
1  | Hi      | def@gmail.com
2  | good    | xyz@gmail.com
```

Looking through a bunch of articles and stack overflow questions, I tried this:

```
SELECT
     STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cr.Email AS [text()]
            FROM Table1 cr1
            WHERE cr1.Email = cr.Email
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS List
FROM  
    Table1 cr
GROUP BY 
    cr.Email
```

**The problem** with the above query is that, it shows me the emails, but they are all repetitive. For example:

```
ID | Summary | Email
---+---------+---------------------------------------------
1  | Hi      | abc@gmail.com
1  | Hi      | def@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, def@gmail.com
2  | good    | xyz@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com
```

So I tried a different approach,

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(250)
SET @tmp = ''

SELECT @tmp = @tmp + cr.Email + ', ' 
FROM Table1 cr

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))
```

**The problem** with the above query is that, it shows me every email in a comma separated list. So every row with a unique ID has all the emails in the

```
ID | Summary | Email
---+---------+--------------------------------------------
1  | Hi      | abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com
2  | good    | abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com
```

**The solution** I am looking for should return this data:

```
ID | Summary | Email
---+---------+------------------------------
1  | Hi      | abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com
2  | good    | xyz@gmail.com
```

What can I do to improve my query, or am I completely steering towards the wrong direction?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are grouping by Email in the initial attempt? You should be grouping by ID and Summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should key off of ID/Summary and not Email

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Summary] varchar(50),[Email] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Hi','abc@gmail.com')
,(1,'Hi','def@gmail.com')
,(2,'good','xyz@gmail.com')


Select A.ID
      ,A.Summary
      ,EMail   = Stuff((Select Distinct ', ' +EMail From @YourTable Where ID=A.ID and Summary=A.Summary For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
 From @YourTable A
 Group By ID,Summary
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Summary EMail
1   Hi      abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com
2   good    xyz@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to chagne this:

```
select 
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cr.Email AS [text()]
   FROM Table1 cr1
   where  cr1.Email = cr.Email
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS List
FROM  Table1 cr
GROUP BY cr.Email
```

To this:

```
select 
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cr.Email AS [text()]
   FROM Table1 cr1
   where  cr1.Email = cr.Email
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS List
FROM  Table1 cr
GROUP BY cr1.ID, cr1.Summary
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want this:

```
SELECT cr.ID,
       cr.Summary,
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cr1.Email
              FROM Table1 cr1
              WHERE cr1.ID = cr.ID
              AND cr1.Summary = cr.Summary
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS List
FROM Table1 cr
GROUP BY cr.ID, cr.Summary
```

The inner `DISTINCT` will prevent the same email from showing up multiple times in a list.  The outer `GROUP BY` will group the email lists in line with their corresponding `ID` and `Summary`